# Lotus Notes - Open file with space character

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

i have to open files using LotusNotes and i tried with this script:

```
dim file as string
file="C:\invoice.pdf"
result=Shell("H:\AdobeReader\AcroRd32.exe "+ file)
```

and it work well.

But when i try to open file where there is a space character in the file name 
(ex: "C:\All Invoice\invoice.pdf")
the command shell recognizes the file name as "C:\All" without all character after the space.
there is someone can help me ?
thank's

Comment: if i try: result=Shell(|H:\AdobeReader\AcroRd32.exe "| + file + |"|) lotus notes send me "illegal function call"

Comment: Did you change something to get it to work or did you use my suggested code?

Comment: i use your exact code, thank's you are great !

Comment: I just made a small edit to the question in order to emphasize that it wasn't Lotus Notes that "recognizes the file name as C:\All".  It is the command shell that recognized it that way.

Comment: It's ok, you are right ! now is better !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the file in quotation marks like this way:

```
Dim file As String
Dim result As variant
file="C:\All Invoice\invoice.pdf"
result=Shell(|H:\AdobeReader\AcroRd32.exe "| + file + |"|)
```